# my ubuntu 16.04 wont update

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, chromebook, crouton

I've tried updating Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 but when I try from GUI it tells me I need permissions and then soon after, it prompts me to update but when I press update, it goes away and nothing happens. I've tried updating via terminal but it gives me this

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                     
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,251 kB]                                                            
Fetched 1,252 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                           
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                    
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [99.8 kB]                
Hit https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                            
Hit https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                      
Hit https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                                 
Get:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease [6,263 B]                
Get:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease [8,041 B]                 
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [99.8 kB]               
Get:5 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-security InRelease [7,518 B]      
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                            
Get:6 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu xenial-infra-updates InRelease [7,475 B]       
Ign https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu jammy InRelease                             
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [326 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [281 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,960 B]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [93.8 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [130 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 1,068 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                           
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

It's worth mentioning that the laptop I'm using is a Chromebook in developer mode using crouton to run ubuntu.

the laptop is powerful enough for the update.

the version of ubuntu running now is Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS 64-bit and to my knowledge, it's running some form of gnome. I'm very new to Linux so I'm not sure.

Comment: You haven't given your architecture; but not all architectures had ESM support, so you may have more difficulties if you're not *amd64* or one of the supported architectures. Once all upgrades for 16.04 are applied you should find upgrades occur; however if your system is a non-ESM supported architecture, a re-install maybe necessary given 16.04 has been *unsupported* for so long, and upgrade requires the system have all updates applied (no longer possible for all architectures).

Comment: ps:  [Ubuntu 16.04 reached EOSS on 30 April 2021](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) so *release-upgrade* should have been done before that date, or shortly after. A re-install is the easiest way when you miss EOL (16.04 support is extended for some architectures via ESM; did you enable ESM? if you didn't that may be your issue depending on where you are in the world & network traffic)

Comment: Check also please if snapd is on your system